# Redirecting all URLs with additional words between two words to non?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a mod-rewrite rule that redirects all URLs that contain anything between `town` & `country` to a new url with nothing in between town and country except a dash.

e.g:

`http://www.example.com/big-town-4-h-country-2j/`

to:

`http://www.example.com/big-town-country-2j/`

I tried this code but nothing happen:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)town.+country(.*)  $1town-country$2
```

My full htaccess code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /?l=$1
RewriteRule (.*)country-(.*)$  country.php?q=$1&l=$2&submit=1 

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !town-country [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)town[^/]+country(.*)$  $1town-country$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Any idea about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498774/return-404-error-for-all-extra-characters-after-second